# How to send a message in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I am using `MFMessageComposeViewController` for sending sms to number of users. When click the button it is navigating to following screen. How Can I send the sms directly when user clicked on the sms button in iOS swift?[image]

```
if (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
    let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    controller.body = "Message Body"
    controller.recipients = ["000","111"]
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
    self.present(controller, animated: true,completion: nil)
}


func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController,
                                  didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult)
{
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not available to directly send the messages with `MFMessageComposeViewController`, it will follow the flow. It will present you with the ComposerView where you have to manually press the send button to send the SMS.

To use without composerView, you should try some [third party API's](https://www.twilio.com/) which can be helpful.

Comment: I need to send offline only

Comment: Well..In that case, it is not available in current iOS version. It is the default behaviour and you should accept it as it is.

Comment: Ok. Thankyou for your reply

Comment: your most welcome.